# Powershell: How can I parse this output?

Tags: powershell

How can I parse this output correctly?

```
$sessionId = qwinsta myUser 

SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>console           myUser                   1  Active

$session.subString(39,9).Trim()
ID
1
```

So far so good. But how can I only get the number without ID? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for fun `( $sessionId -replace '^\s|^>' -replace '(\s+)', ','  )[1].split(',')[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the number use the following as it "appears" $session is an array of strings (one per line of output).

```
$session[1].subString(39,9).Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will capture all digits in your string which are followed by a space(but will leave space out)

```
([regex]::matches($session,"\d+(?= )")).Value
```